# Get youngest child in Firebase users

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to find the youngest user in my list of users and load their data: name, profile pict, and current job assignments. I have read the Firebase primer on querying data, but their examples don't work for me because my data is organized differently. I have an additional child layer.

This is my JSON tree in Firebase:

[image: JSON tree]

I've tried loading the list of users and then iterating over them to find the youngest user, but that seems like overkill. The Firebase documentation makes me think I should be able to do the query through a Firebase method, like 'queryOrderedByChild' or similar.

I've gone over the old documentation [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html) and the new documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data), but I'm still left wondering what to do.

**So this is my workflow:**

The app will find the youngest user in the list of "members" and load their name, profile pict, birthday, etc. They will choose from a list of jobs. Once that user has chosen from the lists of available jobs, the app will load the next youngest user from the list of "members", and so on until all users have been loaded and have been given the chance to select jobs.

I think a better workflow would be this:

1. Get youngest user by utilizing a Firebase query
2. Use that query to load that user (image and name)

How would I go about doing that?

**EDIT #1: Code I've Tried**

```
func loadExistingUsers(completion: @escaping ([[String : Any]]) -> ()) {
    var dictionary = [[String : Any]]()
    ref.child("members").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
            if let value = snap.value as? [String : Any] {
                dictionary.append(value)
            }
        }
        completion(dictionary)
    }
}
```

And then in ViewDidLoad:

```
loadExistingUsers { (dictionary) in

        var youngestBirthday = 19000101
        var userName = "Sophie"

        for item in dictionary {
            let fetchedBirthday = item["birthday"] as! Int
            let fetchedName = item["firstName"] as! String

            if fetchedBirthday > youngestBirthday {
                youngestBirthday = fetchedBirthday
                userName = fetchedName
            }
        }
        print(userName,youngestBirthday)
    }
```

This method returns the youngest user from my list of users, but it seems like an awfully long way to go to get what I want. I have to first fetch the users from Firebase, and then parse the snapshot, then create an array, then sort the array, then get the user name. I was under the impression Firebase could do all that with one query. Am I wrong?

Comment: can you show the code that you have tried?

Comment: updated with info

Comment: Please try this: `ref.child("members").queryOrdered(byChild:"birthday").queryLim‌​ited(toFirst: 1).observe(.childAdded ....`  and see what it gets you in the snapshot by adding `print("Snapshot: \(snapshot)")`

Comment: snapshot returns: `Snapshot: Snap (Dad) {
    birthday = 19780926;
    childParent = parent;
    firstName = Dad;
    gender = male;
    passcode = 1122;
    profileImageUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...";
}`

Comment: So this is the youngest child?

Comment: Oh, I get it (sort of). If I change the `queryLimited` call to `toLast` (because in my dataset, younger people have birthdays with larger numbers), it returns `Snapshot: Snap (Trixie) {
    birthday = 20030927;
    childParent = child;
    firstName = Trixie;
    gender = female;
    passcode = 4534;
    profileImageUrl = "https://firebasestorage...` which is exactly the info I was looking for. So now the question is how to parse it...

Comment: So the Firebase call `queryOrdered` creates an ordered list from which it then can call `first` or `last`, which will give me my largest or smallest number. Is it like Firebase is creating an array online (using the `query` method, and then I can access that array using the `observe` method? I'm just trying to figure out the logic of the code you gave me.

Comment: Yes you are on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the youngest child using this code: (since your youngest date is the largest number so I am using `toLast`)

```
ref.child("members").queryOrdered(byChild:"birthday").queryL‌​im‌​ited(toLast: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                        if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                                let name = value["firstname"] as? String
                                //you can do for other values as well
                                print(name)

                        }
                })
```

Comment: Perfect. Works! It was the `query` in connection with the `observe` methods that had me stumped. Now I get it. Thanks!